# Logging the requests,response and errors in Yii 1.1.15

Tags: php, logging, yii

How to log all the requests and their corresponding responses in Yii, I tried to log the requests in afterAction, but how to get the responses in afterAction. I also need to log all the  errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`afterRender`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#afterRender-detail) function to get the rendered output. The `$output` parameter gives you the rendered output. But I think this works only when you have used render function in your controller actions.

Add following to your components configuration in your config file to log errors and warnings

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
```